# Issue installing Azure AD Connect ADFS Health Agent

Tags: windows-server-2016, adfs, entra-id

I'm trying to install the Azure AD Connect ADFS health agent on the primary server in an ADFS 4.0 farm running on Windows Server 2016.

The installation completes successfully but I get an error on configuration:

```
Register-AzureADConnectHealthADFSAgent : Could not query the MEX on http ports: 443 in hosts: localhost
At line:1 char:190
+ ... gent\PowerShell\AdHealthAdfs; Register-AzureADConnectHealthADFSAgent}
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Register-AzureADConnectHealthADFSAgent], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Identity.Health.Adfs.PowerShell.Configuration
   Module.RegisterADHealthAdfsAgent
```

Now I've run that error through the google and it tells me that this could be a [STS certificate issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0decc685-891a-4e88-9b1f-0828b553f29b/error-while-installing-azure-ad-connect-health-for-ad-fs-agent?forum=ADFS) so I've checked as per [the article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2e8f7ff6-7088-4e51-b2a6-057f34dfd883/secondary-ad-fs-server-not-authenticating-event-15021?forum=ADFS) pointed at there, and there are no issues, no other unexpected or incorrect certificate thumbprint visible, and besides on ADFS 4.0 you can't change certificates on the secondary servers in an ADFS farm, so even simply trying to re-register the certs didn't help.

Running further diags as per maweeras' suggestions:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL> $error[0] | fl * -f


PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.InvalidOperationException: Could not query the MEX on http ports: 443 in hosts:
                        localhost
                           at Microsoft.Identity.Health.Adfs.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.AdfsServiceExaminer.GetAdfs
                        FarmNameFromSts()
                           at Microsoft.Identity.Health.Adfs.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.AdfsServiceExaminer.Compute
                        ServiceSignature()
                           at Microsoft.Identity.Health.Common.Clients.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.RegisterADHealthA
                        gent.ProcessRecord()
                           at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Register-AzureADConnectHealthADFSAgent], InvalidOperationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Identity.Health.Adfs.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.
                        RegisterADHealthAdfsAgent
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

The install/config log doesn't seem to tell us anything that isn't already here. I can browse to the MEX endpoint via its FQDN in a web browser.

Comment: It would be more useful if you post the output from below command immediately after command fails. $error[0] | fl * -f

Comment: You should also have a peak at logs in %localappdata%\temp for clues as the AAD Connect Health installer writes logs there. All I can see is an apparent error to get to the /adfs/services/trust/mex endpoint.

Comment: Does get-adfssslcertificate show a 443 binding for localhost ?

Comment: @maweeras none of the servers in the farm have any kind of binding for localhost when I run that command. Should they have?

Comment: yes it should be there

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the issue. I just need to figure out how to add that binding then I should be ok hopefully. I'll let you know, if it works so you can post an answer for the free internet points

Comment: Is this farm using certauth as a name it listens on out of interest?

Comment: pardon my ignorance but how do I check? I don't believe it's configured for device auth (iirc that's certauth?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74440/discussion-between-maweeras-and-rob-moir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like localhost specific SNI binding for TLS was missing. get-adfssslcertificate should reveal a 443 binding for both hostname used for actual service and localhost.

If missing, set-adfssslcertificate is the way to fix missing bindings. This will allow the health agent install to succeed.